# What is logarithmic mapping in a filter bank such as the one in the human ear?

Tags: filters, audio, speech-processing, filter-bank

"The spacing of the filters in a filter bank used to make an ordinary spectrogram is linear, whereas an auditory filter bank has a spacing that corresponds to the way in which sinusoidal frequency maps onto place on the basilar membrane, a so-called tonotopic map. For frequencies of about 1kHz and above, this mapping is logarithmic."

I read this in an article about how the ear works in processing sound. Can someone explain mathematically how the mapping for frequencies of about 1 kHz and above is logarithmic? Also it would be appreciated if anyone can suggest some literature regarding this topic.

Comment: I don't think mathematical proof for logarithmic scaling will be there. it should be experimental observation that human ears sensitivity is logarithmic.

Comment: What is the meaning of logarithmic scaling? How to scale something logarithmically?

Comment: have you heard about Mel scale/Mel filter bank ? the frequency bins are scaled logarithmically to extract features/ representaion..

Comment: Nope. I will check it out